# Add transitions to jQuery style changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

First of all I should ask if it's possible to add transitions to this so it looks more smooth, not so "laggy".

This is the script I'd like to add a transition, it just changes the style of some elements when you scroll down or up:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    div.css("height", "50px");
    pic.css({ width : "400px", height : "50px" });
    text.hide();
    menu.css("top", "0px");
});
```

Check out my entire code here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9j1cf51b/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the CSS property `transition` to an element.

To make a smooth transition 1s long, on all animatable properties of an element you can do :

```
#element {
    transition: 1s;
}
```

There are also other options such as easing functions and selecting specific properties to animate :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: I love you, that really nice!

Answer (score 2):

CSS transitions are one way to go. That way you can just remove and add classes in your JavaScript to trigger them.

[Here's your fiddle with some css transitions](http://jsfiddle.net/z9yczf9k/1/) though I left some for you to finish =D

```
.maindiv {
    ...
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.maindiv.collapsed {
    height: 50px;
}
```

JS

```
if (st > lastScrollTop){
  div.addClass('collapsed');
  ...       
} else {
  div.removeClass('collapsed');
  ...
}
```